# Why doesn't linq to xml recognize my the attributes in my XML file?

Tags: .net, linq

I'm brand new to LINQ to XML (comfortable with LINQ to sql) and learning my way around with this tutorial
http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/01/08/linq-to-xml-tutorial/

When I write this linq query

```
Dim data As XDocument = XDocument.Load(xmlFileLocation)
Dim outputFileLoc = (From c In data.Descendants("Program") Where c.Attribute("ProgramName").Equals("EnviroEpi") Select c)
```

on this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Programs>
   <Program ProgramName="EnviroEpi">
      <Type>csv</Type>
      <Location>test</Location>
   </Program>
   <Program ProgramName="Epi">
       <Type>HL7</Type>
       <Location>test</Location>
   </Program>
   <Program ProgramName="Lead">
      <Type>csv</Type>
      <Location>test</Location>
   </Program>
</Programs>
```

I get an error:

> Sequence contains no elements

Does this mean that LINQ can't see the `ProgramName` attribute of my program nodes? Or am I missing something else? As far as I can tell, I'm doing everything exactly like in the tutorial.

Thanks again for the help. I'm really just getting a feel for LINQ to XML.

**Edit**

```
... where c.attribute("ProgramName").Equals("EnviroEpi") // returns no elements.
```

This works:

```
 c.attribute("ProgramName").value.equals("EnviroEpi") //added in .value to get it to work
```

Comment: First of all - that's no valid XML that you have there..... you should have an opening `<Type>` - then your value - and then a closing `</Type>` - same for `<Location>....</Location>`  ....

Comment: Please add your own answer as the definitive answer, and mark that as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `Descendants("Programs").Descendants`, that would return *any descendant* of the `Programs` elements - most of which are unrelated and don't have a ProgramName attribute, hence you get a `NullReferenceException`.

You also need to use `Attribute("ProgramName").value.Equals("EnviroEpi")` to get to the value of the program name attribute.

You want `Descendants("Program")` instead:

```
 Dim outputFileLoc = (From c In data.Descendants("Program") Where c.Attribute("ProgramName").Equals("EnviroEpi") Select c).First
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that `data.Descendants("Programs")` or `data.Descendants("Programs").Descendants` is null. You need to do null checks along the way, you can't really just chain a bunch of objects together like you've done.